# Как заблокировать изменение приложения под черную тему телефона?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Я не хочу что бы моя тема приложения xamarin менялась. Я использую

Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light;

Но это не работает, мне нужна только белая тема.

Comment: Странно, если я как юзер выбрал темную тему, значит мне не нравится, когда всё белое, верно? ОС предоставляет вам великолепную возможность вообще не думать об этом. Но вы придумали из этого проблему, почему?

Comment: Я уже решил это, а согласно выбора юзера то я делаю программу для себя, мне это было неважно, слишком громоздко делать темную тему для 1-2 людей

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813162/12888024 Xamarin не знаю, но судя по тому что прочитал, не везде этот код сработает. Где вы его вставляете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил вопрос этим кодом в style.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```